# Deployment to Azure Data Factory from DevOps. Template character changes

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-data-factory

I have setup a Azure Data Factory and Azure DevOps to deploy continuously in to other env. But in the parameters we have  a Finnish character **ä**. Which will be  changed to **?** After deploying from Azure DevOps. We are using ARM template to do the deployment from DevOps. What needs to be done so the character will not be changed as We are manually making changes after the deployment?
It will be great help if any suggestions we get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solution for the issue. When we check in the code form TFS 2017 it saved the file with Western Windows-1252 Encoding format. Our Azure Data factory ARM TEMPLATE format processing was UTF-8 encoding format. When we checked in the ARM TEMPLATE we saved the file as UTF-8 and the character was correctly visible in Azure Data factory

Answer (score 0):

The Data Factory name can contain only letters, numbers and hyphens. The first and last characters must be a letter or number and spaces are not allowed.

Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/naming-rules

Comment: We are not using special characters in data factory name. In pipeline we have one stage where the parameter is in Finnish character. Which we used for writing a query. That changes to unknown character while we deploy from ARM TEMPLATE. in arm template that character is correct but after deployment it changes

Comment: Thank you for clarifying your issue. Can you please put some screenshots of the pipeline stage and query in your question ?

Comment: I am unable to upload as I am new to stack overflow. I have shared a link of the image **https://ibb.co/rpgm25T**